# currentUser is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm new to programming and following this video, my code until now has had no problems, but when I try

```
console.log(currentUser);
```

It returns undefined while it shouldn't, the user is logged in and all of their information is correct in Firebase. Also, my code doesn't show any errors.

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchUser } from '../../redux/actions/index';

export class Main extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }
    render() {
        const { currentUser } = this.props;

        console.log(currentUser)
        if (currentUser==undefined){
            return(
                <View></View>)
        }
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text>User is logged in</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser
})
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({fetchUser}, dispatch)

export default connect(null, mapDispatchProps)(Main);
```

And this is the parent component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

require('dotenv').config();
import firebase from 'firebase';
const firebaseConfig = {
//personal info
};
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))


if(firebase.apps.length === 0){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import LandingScreen from './Components/auth/Landing';
import RegisterScreen from './Components/auth/Register';
import MainScreen from './Components/auth/Main';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user){
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: false,
          loaded: true,
        })
      }else{
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true,
          loaded: true,
        })
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { loggedIn, loaded } = this.state
    if (!loaded){
      return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

    if (!loggedIn) {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
            <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainScreen/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }

    
};

export default App
```

Comment: In order for <Main> component to work as intended, there must be a parent that is passing fetchUser() and currentUser props, as these are being called within the <Main> component. Could you show the parent component code also?

Comment: I will ad it in the question

Comment: You don't show us the value you get back from the API nor how you store it in the redux store. You're looking up `store.userState.currentUser` which isn't set in the store. So you're either looking up the wrong object, or you're setting the value incorrectly. Neither of those behaviors are in the code you posted.

Comment: Agreed with @Andy that there is not enough info.  Can you check and see if your `fetchUser` action is being called correctly?  Is the request failing and dispatching an error action (or doing nothing) instead of a success action?